# How can I determine if Facebook is hitting my page?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Does anyone know how to check in ASP.NET (C#) if Facebook is scraping a page? I'd like to be able to check on the server side if the "browser" hitting the page is actually Facebook (e.g. when it grabs details when a user is attempting to share a link).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether `Request.UserAgent` contains `Facebook`.

Comment: I checked for lowercase "facebook" and that seems to have done the trick. Let's hope Facebook don't come out with their own browser now.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the referrer .... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

Comment: Referrer will not be set if Facebook servers perform direct request. It will only be set if Facebook server directs the client browser to the OP server.